# failing to decompile resources-file using apktool

Tags: android

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResStringValue cannot be cast to
>   brut.androlib.res.data.value.ResAttr  at
>   brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResAttrDecoder.decode(ResAttrDecoder.java:36)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.decoder.AXmlResourceParser.getAttributeValue(AXmlResourceParser.java:369)
>     at
>   org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.XmlPullParserDelegate.getAttributeValue(XmlPullParserDelegate.java:69)
>     at
>   org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.writeStartTag(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:267)
>     at
>   org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.event(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:211)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder$1.event(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:83)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decode(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:141)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decodeManifest(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:153)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResFileDecoder.decodeManifest(ResFileDecoder.java:134)
>     at
>   brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.decode(AndrolibResources.java:296)
>     at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeResourcesFull(Androlib.java:131)    at
>   brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:101)  at
>   brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:165)    at
>   brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:81)

---

i am failing decode resources-file. i installed all the softwares that are needed by i still get this error. Please help guys

Comment: Why not use dexplorer app on your phone to do this? You can also try an app called show Java.

Comment: Update apktool to at least `2.0.3`. The cast from `ResStringValue` to `ResAttr` was fixed.